# How to get project dimension in Foundry Nuke?

Tags: python, nuke

I'm trying to get the dimension of the project (`format`), which, in the layman term *height* and *width* of the project for further processing. While reading documentation on [Formats documentation](https://docs.thefoundry.co.uk/nuke/63/pythondevguide/formats.html) on  Nuke Python developer's guide, I found that to get the width and height of project, one must select any node in script, e.g.

```
# Viewer1 is only generic thing in every project
nuke.toNode("Viewer1").setSelected(True)
projwidth = nuke.selectedNode().format().width()
projheight = nuke.selectedNode().format().height()
```

But this produces some adverse effect on the node graph. The gizmo is connected to Viewer1, even if I append `nuke.toNode("Viewer1").setSelected(False)` to the end of the above line.

[Here's](https://github.com/santosh/.nuke/blob/9121172f3c38d75a7b82ebf6670f0ecd70543610/playground/trailer.py#L36-L54) the code if you want to see the whole script.

This overall process seems so nasty. Is there anything wrong I'm doing? What could be the possible fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the project's Viewer dimensions using this line in `Script Editor`:

```
nuke.tcl('knob root.format ' '4K_DCP')
```

Pay attention there is a `space` after `root.format`.

Also you should put these lines in `init.py` or `menu.py` in `.nuke` folder if you wanna use your own format (automatically):

```
import nuke

Format_1600 = "1600 900 0 0 1600 900 1 Format_1600"
nuke.addFormat(Format_1600)
nuke.knobDefault("Root.format", "Format_1600")
```

Where: `1600 900 0 0 1600 900 1 Format_1600` is:

```
# width = 1600, height = 900
# x = 0, y = 0, right = 1600, top = 900
# pixel aspect = 1 (square pixels)
# name = Format_1600
```

Or you can choose any existing format from nuke list:

```
nuke.knobDefault('Root.format', 'HD_1080')
```

> And, of course, you can `get` dimensions and other values of the project's format:

```
nuke.root()['format'].value().width()
nuke.root()['format'].value().height()

nuke.root()['format'].value().name()
nuke.root()['format'].value().pixelAspect()
nuke.root()['format'].value().x()
nuke.root()['format'].value().y()
nuke.root()['format'].value().r()
nuke.root()['format'].value().t()
```

Comment: But I don't want to *set* project format. I want to *get* it. I'm working on a script which needs to calculate the center of working area. Which only could be done after calculating the work area (format).

Comment: Ok, I'll add lines how to get it.